# Ubuntu 14.04 Custom Unity Lenses don't appear in the dash

Tags: unity, 14.04, lenses

I have Ubuntu 14.04 and I have installed custom unity lenses, the pirate bay torrent lens for example, but they aren't appearing in the dash.  I have logged out and back in, and I have rebooted the computer.  I even did Alt-F2 and typed Unit --replace.  Nothing seems to have gone wrong as I watched the install.  They just don't show up.  Is there something else I am supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

I've just installed the tpb lens. You can search with:

> tpb:your search

or

> torrent:your search

it doesn't add an icon at dash's bottom anymore. However, it's not finding anything for me :S (you can tell if it's been used displaying the Filters and making sure Torrent get highlighted)

Answer (score 0):

I get the same problem: i make a search like "torrent:heart" and as I type the torrent lens filter gets highlighted looks like searching but after a moment the search stops and the filter goes off (as if i would have removed it myself)